# Postgresql using LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN at the same time

Tags: postgresql, join, temporary-tables

I have two temporary tables that I have created using `tampa`, `tampb` clauses in PostgreSQL. I want to be able to get result when data from either side is missing (`company1` or `company2`) but not both.

I have tried to use `FULL JOIN` but it does not work.

This is my sample SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           WITH tempa AS (
               SELECT a.id,
                      a.name,
                      a.section,
                      a.photo,
                      a."company1",
                      b."company2"
               FROM   (
                          SELECT a.id,
                                 s.name,
                                 s.section,
                                 s.photo,
                                 m.salary_company AS "company1",
                                 a.id
                          FROM   salary a
                                 JOIN pension b
                                      ON  a.pension_id = b.id
                                 JOIN company m
                                      ON  (
                                              m.id = a.salary_company_id JOIN users s ON s.id = a.users_id WHERE a.id = 
                                              35
                                              AND m.salary_company_id = 35
                                              AND a.amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY a.pension_id,
                                              s.section,
                                              a.id,
                                              m.salary_company,
                                              s.name,
                                              s.roll,
                                              s.photo
                                          ) AS a
                                 LEFT JOIN (
                                          SELECT a.id,
                                                 s.name,
                                                 s.section,
                                                 s.photo,
                                                 m.salary_company AS "company2",
                                                 a.id
                                          FROM   salary a
                                                 JOIN pension b
                                                      ON  a.pension_id = b.id
                                                 JOIN company m
                                                      ON  (
                                                              m.id = a.salary_company_id JOIN users s ON s.id = 
                                                              a.users_id WHERE a.id = 22
                                                              AND m.salary_company_id = 22
                                                              AND a.amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY a.pension_id,
                                                              s.section,
                                                              a.id,
                                                              m.salary_company,
                                                              s.name,
                                                              s.roll,
                                                              s.photo
                                                          ) AS b
                                                      ON  a.id = b.id
                                      ),
                                 tempb AS (
                                     SELECT *,
                                            COALESCE("company1", 0) + COALESCE("company2", 0) AS total,
                                            ROUND(
                                                (
                                                    (COALESCE("company1", 0) + COALESCE("company2", 0))::NUMERIC / (2)::
                                                    NUMERIC
                                                ),
                                                2
                                            ) AS average
                                     FROM   tempa
                                 )

SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER(ORDER BY average DESC) AS RANK
FROM   tempb) f WHERE f.id = 481
```

When data is available in `company2` but not in `company1`, this SQL returns results (which is perfect because of `LEFT JOIN`) but I want to return results when either data are available in `company1` and not in `company2` or data are available in `company2` and not in `company1`.
I have tried `FULL JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN, FULL INNER JOIN` all does not work.

I will appreciate any advice given.

Final Results I want to obtain should look as follows

```
 
 
Name  Company1 Company2  Sum  Rank 

John $2000     $3000   $5000   1   
Doe  $1000     $2000   $3000   2
 
Eli   $500     $1000   $1900   3
```

Comment: I ignored the code dump (it is invalid). You might clean up and focus on the core of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming compatible row types for `tempa` and `tempb` and you want exactly *one* result row, this is one of many possible solutions:

```
WITH cte AS (
   (SELECT ... LIMIT 1)  -- tempa
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT ... LIMIT 1)  -- tempb
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE (SELECT count(*) = 1 FROM cte);
```

Or for any number of result rows:

```
WITH tempa AS (SELECT ...)
   , tempb AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT * FROM tempa WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempb)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tempb;
```

Comment: Thanks **Erwin Brandstetter**, but using `UNION ALL` will create two rows which  will not give me exactly output I need. May you suggest an alternative to give me one row after joining ?

Comment: @Ephra: Please clarify in the question how many rows *can* come from each subquery (0-n?) and how many rows you want in the result - and which to pick if we there can be more in a single subquery. Then notify me again.

Comment: Hello @Erwin, depending on the number of `company(x)` available in the table, I can join as many `companies` to do the comparison, so I usually generate this SQL in PHP codes to give me number of companies I need to join.